# Retrieving computed subset of columns in doctrine

Tags: php, rest, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I want to develop a RESTful API based on Slim Framework and Doctrine 2. I have a detailed permission management. So I have permissions defined as:
`role:admin|entity:person|column:name|write:1`
Im considering the most effective way to implement the right management into the web service.
Therefore I need to filter a  computed subset of columns when building my query. What is the best place to do that, still enabling me to use all the default methods like findAll() etc. I could of course filter my fields like below:

```
 $all = Article::createQuery('a')->getArrayResult();
 /*this is getting ALL the fields -it would be better to filter before 
   retrieving from the db
 */
 $allFiltered = array();
 foreach($all as $index=>$article){
  $filteredArticle = new Article();
  foreach($user->getPermission('Article','r') as $permission){
    $column = $permission->column;
    $filteredArticle->$column = $article->$column;
   }
 $allFiltered[$index]=$filteredArticle
)
 $app->response->setBody(json_encode($all));
```

Is there a way to do this at one place for all retrieving methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Doctrrine2 can select partial object [doc](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html)
You can fetch all permitted columns and just concatenate with a query ...

Comment: Yes I read about that - but what's the best place to modify ALL queries ( those generated by findBy etc) ?

Comment: Well, I am do not use slim framework. ... You can implement ObjectRepository class for each entity  ... but I don't know would you have an access to user instance

Comment: So the right way would be to have an EntityRepository which has its own query builder and  all  other entiy repository should inherit from ? Since I can get the user data from the session at any time so I guess this would not bee an issue.

Comment: All custom logic to fetch data I place in repository. It is a one solid place and logic not spread across a project.